# useState with callback not updating useCallback dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

I have made a working example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-flower-o0gyn?file=/src/App.js

When I click the hide button I want to save the updated data to localstorage:

1. I click hide on first column: `setValueWithCallback` runs, sets the callback to a ref & sets the state
2. `useEffect` kicks in, calls the callback with the updated data
3. `saveToLocalStorage` is called, in a `useCallback` with `data` set as a dependency

The problem is at the 3rd step, what gets saved to localstorage is `{visible: true}` for both.
I know if I change this line:

```
const saveToLocalStorage = useCallback(() => {
  localStorage.setItem(
    `_colProps`,
    JSON.stringify(data.map((e) => ({ id: e.id, visible: e.visible })))
  );
}, [data]);
```

To this:

```
const saveToLocalStorage = localStorage.setItem(
  `_colProps`,
  JSON.stringify(data.map((e) => ({ id: e.id, visible: e.visible })))
);
```

It works, but I cannot get my head around, why it does not with the first. I assume it must be some closure thing, but I don't see it.

If `data` has already been updated, and `useEffect` ran the callback, why it is not updated in the dependencies array?.
Yes, the example is weird and the 2nd solution is perfectly fine, I just wanted to demonstrate the problem.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Shouldn't this `useCallback(() => {` be `useCallback((data) => {`? You are passing an argument to the callback function but your callback function definition doesn't takes any parameters.

Comment: I don't think you need parameters. If you check the react docs it is used without parameters.

Comment: So the callback function _magically_ has access to the argument values? In your code example, `data` is the local state of the component, not the argument that you pass when you call `callbackRef.current(data);`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear about that. I don't care about the parameter. Inside of the callback I'm referencing the local state of the component. I just wanted to have a mechanism that first updates the state and when it is done calls the callback (saving to localstorage). Shouldn't the `data` in the dependencies array be already updated when the callback fire? If you click on the other button after the first click, one object is saved correctly, so it is behind a cycle.

Comment: I might misunderstand how `useCallback` work. I thought when something in the dependencies array change it generates a new function with the most up-to-date values inside of its body.

Comment: @marchello I thought the same...it's confusing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem in your code is because of a closure of `saveToLocalStorage` function over the local state of the component.

Inside the `setValueWithCallback` function, you save the reference to the `saveToLocalStorage` function using the `callback` parameter that is passed to `setValueWithCallback` function and this is where your problem is.

`useCallback` hook will update the function reference of `saveToLocalStorage` function but you *do not* call that updated function. Instead, you call the function you saved in `callbackRef.current` which is not the updated function, but an old one which has a closure over the state with value of `visible` property in both objects set to `true`.

#### Solution

You can solve this problem by passing in the `data` as an argument to the callback function. You already pass the argument when you call `callbackRef.current(data)` but you don't make use of it inside the `saveToLocalStorage` function.

Change the `saveToLocalStorage` to make use of the argument that is passed from inside of the `useEffect` hook.

```
const saveToLocalStorage = useCallback((updatedData) => {
    localStorage.setItem(
      `_colProps`,
      JSON.stringify(updatedData.map((e) => ({ id: e.id, visible: e.visible })))
    );
}, []);
```

Another way to solve this problem is to get rid of `callbackRef` and just call the `saveToLocalStorage` function from inside of the `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    saveToLocalStorage();
}, [data, saveToLocalStorage]);
```

Comment: Thanks, now I see it. Unfortunately, I cannot use the `useEffect` version, because I already have a drag event that fires like a couple hundred times per second setting `data` and that would probably not healthy for localStorage writes.
So, I went with the first variant, but I ditched `useCallback` completely, just passing the argument to a regular function.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` is of array type and react only do `shallow comparison` when an state update occur, so basically it will check for `data` reference change not for its value change. That is why, your saveToLocalStorage not re-initiated when `data's` value changes.

Comment: No, that is not the case because data is getting a new reference each time you click. And If you click the other button after the first, you see the localstorage updating, but still behind one cycle.